# startup applications not opening up in full screen

Tags: 14.04

We are using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. We have added Firefox to the startup application. the browser does open up but not into full screen mode. There are 2 arrows next to the Firefox browser and if you right click on this icon you can see it has opened up. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For complete fullscreen, you can add *-fullscreen* to the end of your startup command.

The other alternative is to just open Firefox, maximize the window, then close the window manually. From now on, it *should* re-open maximized.

Comment: I looked through firefox's man page , and it doesnt seem to have the `-fullscreen` option, though

Comment: Oh, sorry, after further reading, that option is due to an extension called *Autohide*, which I can't find any further information on. Sorry for that one. Does Firefox re-open maximized if you close from maximized? It does for me (including F11 fullscreen).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `xdotool` and changing the startup command to

```
sh -c 'setsid firefox; sleep 3; xdotool key F11'
```

The `xdotool` utility emulates keypresses, so you're effectively saying "open firefox,wait 3 seconds, simulate pressing F11 key to enter full screen". The `setsid firefox` is necessary to start firefox as a session leader and detach from `sh`, to allow other commands to execute.

This of course relies on the assumption that within 3 seconds of starting the  command, firefox will be the foreground window; otherwise `xdotool` will send F11 keypress to whatever toplevel window is at that moment. To cover all possible corner cases, a much longer script could be needed.

Adjust the `sleep` seconds accordingly to match how long your firefox takes to start.